# is JSON better then XML for something with so much data "classification"

Tags: android, ios, xml, json, html

Hello how would I go about storing data in JSON opposed to using XML, like the example below

This is for a mobile app that's updated online from a single domain by a single user.

[image]

My XML path is as follows the site will show the Categories first > genres for selected category > list items for selected genre > List item from selected genre (each is a new page) calling the data from JSON array or some kind of nesting?  this is one of 5 categories, each could have upto 20 genres and list of 10-50 plus, per genre. each list item has a 200-word description, img path and title....

```
    <category>
        <category-name>category one</category-name>
        <category-description>what is category one about</category-description>
        <genres>          
            <genre> <!-- start of genre -->
            <name>genre one</name>
            <description>what is genre one about</description>
                <list>
                    <item>
                        <img></img>
                        <name></name>
                        <description></description>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <img></img>
                        <name></name>
                        <description></description>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <img></img>
                        <name></name>
                        <description></description>
                    </item>
                </list>
            </genre>

            <genre> <!-- start of genre -->
            <name>genre two</name>
            <description>what is genre two about</description>
                <list>
                    <item>
                        <img></img>
                        <name></name>
                        <description></description>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <img></img>
                        <name></name>
                        <description></description>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <img></img>
                        <name></name>
                        <description></description>
                    </item>
                </list>
            </genre>
        </genres>
    </category>
    <!-- now add another 4+ categories as big as the above-->
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward. JSON is a modern standard, and it has arguably better/cleaner support in both the browser and in native applications. Here's a simple conversion, let me know what you think.

```
[
    {
    "category-name" : "category one",
    "category-description" : "what is category one about",
    "genres" : [
        {
            "genre-name" : "genre one",
            "genre-description" : "what is genre one about",
            "list" : [
                {
                    "img" : "",
                    "name" : "",
                    "description" : ""
                },
                {
                    "img" : "",
                    "name" : "",
                    "description" : ""
                },
                {
                    "img" : "",
                    "name" : "",
                    "description" : ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "genre-name" : "genre two",
            "genre-description" : "what is genre two about",
            "list" : [
                {
                    "img" : "",
                    "name" : "",
                    "description" : ""
                },
                {
                    "img" : "",
                    "name" : "",
                    "description" : ""
                },
                {
                    "img" : "",
                    "name" : "",
                    "description" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, ...
]
```

Comment: Simple yet straightforward. JSON is better, cleaner and has a lot of available libraries in different languages.

Comment: @TTillage Looks really good! thanks. how would I go about making a page for the categories then once a category is clicked it shows the genres within that category only (new page) and then once again once a genre is selected (new page) lists items within that genre only then once a list item is selected (new page) show that item img, name description ? is there an easy jquery way to do this? I say jQuery as i find it easier to understand..again thanks for all your help!

Comment: whats this bit for `}, ...` (the dots)

Comment: The dots are to indicate that it can be an endless array. You must remove the `, ...` for it to be valid JSON.

Comment: Your other question is a much larger one. Since you mentioned JQuery I assume you are building a website. There are many questions you need to answer, such as what are your target devices (desktop-only site, mobile site, etc...), where is your site content stored (a database like mySQL or MongoDB), how is information getting from the database to your client (web services).

Comment: I would suggest reading up on MVC frameworks like AngularJS and Backbone.js. You can also go the server-side-rendering approach with Node.js and a framework like Express. Either is suitable depending on your needs, which you need to carefully define. JQuery alone is just a collection of helper methods, not an organizing factor for any website.